# Submit Search query and show results without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery

I have an input box and upon submit, it checks the database for the results, refreshes the page and then displays the results.

Is there a way to prevent the page refreshing when it displays the results?

Here's my script:

```
    <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php echo $results; ?>

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass","dbname");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['search']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 
$r_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
$results = $row['username'];  
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Try jquery for sending request to server

Comment: @PareshGami Are there any tutorials on for that, as I'm not completely familiar with jquery?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 0):

Let's give an id to that form:

```
<form method="post" id="my-test">
<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Let's write a handler for it:

```
function submitMyTest(e) {
    //We do not want to reload the page
    e.preventDefault();
    //gather inputs
    var inputs = $(this).find("input[name],textarea[name]");
    var data = {};
    inputs.each(function() {
        data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yoururl/yourpage.php',
        medhot: 'POST'
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            //handle response
        }
    })
}
```

And somewhere, maybe inside a load event attach this to the submit of your tag, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#my-test").submit(submitMyTest);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `html5` **`pushstate()`** and **`popstate()`** functions. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Create one `id` as `target` in `<form>`. Use this `id` in `<script></script>`.

**2)** Create one `<div></div>` with class name as `showResult`. All result will come & sit in this `<div>` only.

```
<form id="target">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search_name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<div class="showResult"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#target").submit(function( event ) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        var search_name=$('#search_name').val();
        $.ajax({url:"AjaxPage.php?search_name="+search_name,cache:false,success:function(result){
          $('.showResult').html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

**AjaxPage.php** (Create new page & Make sure this page name is same as you used in `<script></script>`. Both are related.)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass","dbname");

$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['search_name']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 
$r_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
    echo $row['username'];  
}
?>
```